# Lower bound of an inductively defined sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have a sequence $U_{n}$, defined as : $U_0=5$, and $U_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(U_n+\frac{5}{U_n})$.

I'm trying to prove that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $U_n \geq \sqrt{5}$.

---

I've tried to prove that using proof by induction :

Base case : $U_0=5$, true

Assumption : $U_n\geq \sqrt{5}$.

proof :  Okay i started with $\frac{5}{U_n}\leq \frac{5}{\sqrt{5}}$ .... but i can continue.

Comment: Try bringing $U_{n+1}-\sqrt{5}$ into a form where it's clear that it is non-negative.

Comment: @DanielFischer induction ?

Answer (score 5):

This follows immediately from AM-GM. It is not hard to show that $U_n > 0$ for all $n$. We then have
$$U_{n+1} = \dfrac12\left(U_n + \dfrac5{U_n}\right) \geq \sqrt{\left(U_n \cdot \dfrac5{U_n}\right)} = \sqrt5$$
Equivalently, we have
$$U_{n+1} - \sqrt5 = \dfrac12\left(U_n + \dfrac5{U_n}\right)-\sqrt5 = \dfrac1{2U_n}\left(U_n^2 - 2U_n \sqrt5 + (\sqrt5)^2\right) = \dfrac{(U_n-\sqrt5)^2}{2U_n}$$

Using this you can now prove that $U_n$ converges to $\sqrt5$. Show that $U_{n+1} < U_n$, i.e., $U_n$ is a strictly decreasing sequence. Now, since $U_n$ is bounded below by $\sqrt5$, by completeness axiom, a monotone decreasing sequence bounded below converges. Hence, $\lim_{n \to \infty} U_n$ exists. Calling the limit as $L$, and noting that $L>0$, we obtain
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} U_{n+1} = \dfrac12\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} U_n + \dfrac5{\lim_{n \to \infty} U_n}\right) \implies L = \dfrac12\left(L+\dfrac5L\right) \implies L^2 = 5 \implies L = \sqrt5$$

Comment: this shows that $U_{n+1}\geq \sqrt{5}$ which is not required or you are trying to continue the proof by induction ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternate method:

$U_n$ satisfies the quadratic equation $$U_n^2-2U_{n+1}U_{n}+5=0.$$ So this equation has a real root. The discriminant, $4U_{n+1}^2-4\cdot5$ is non-negative. from this, it follows that $U_{n+1}\ge\sqrt 5$.

Comment: do you continue the proof by induction ?

Comment: @Antaraz No. This shows directly that the inequality holds for all $n\ge 0$.  (It also holds for $U_0$ of course.)

Comment: DavidMitra what inequality ?

Comment: Well, so proving that $U_n \ge \sqrt{5}$ is the same as proving $U_{n+1} \ge \sqrt{5}$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means for $U_n$ and $\displaystyle\frac5{U_n}$.